# Split ListView items into two columns

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to split an item in a ListView to get the same result as the ListView in Samsung's Contact phones list:

[image: Samsung contact list]

When clicking on the left/right column, only that column's background changes. I tried inserting an Image Button to a one column list view, but when not clicking directly on the button, the whole row's background changes (including the ImageButton's background).

How is it possible to get the same ListView as the of Samsung?

Answer (score 1):

I used this code and it work for me good

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="trtrtrt" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `android:listSelector="@null"` in list's xml and if it does not work then I want to have a look into your code if you can post it.